# What metric should be minimized when trying to find a subset of points from a given set so that the selected points are uniformly distributed?

Tags: minimize, minimization, evolutionary-algorithm, uniform-distribution, fitness

Given a set of *n* points, I have to find a subset of given size *m<size(n)*, so that the points in the selected subset are as uniformly distributed as possible across the volume enclosed by the convex hull of set *n*.

I am solving this problem using Evolutionary Algorithm (EA). The parameters of the problem are the *n* points and the size *m*. What is the objective function to be minimized? Each generation, EA finds solutions, where each solution is *m* points from set *n*. How to measure which solution is better, meaning which points are more uniformly distributed?

I tried minimizing electrostatic potential
($$E=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j\frac{1}{|r_i-r_j|}$$)
following the idea of the [Thomson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem), however the resulting output is clearly incorrect as the density of the selected points is higher at the edges. I tried squaring values in denominator of given equation for E, but the solutions are still clearly sub-optimal.

What is the objective function I should minimize to get what I want? Note that I want to solve this problem in **high dimension space for arbitrary set of points** with unknown distribution.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am not an expert on this topic)

You may be interested in finding a set with [low discrepancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence).
From the Wikipedia page :

> With these definitions, discrepancy represents the worst-case or maximum point density deviation of a uniform set.

So I guess it makes sense to try to find the set of *m*  (among your *n*) points minimizing such discrepancy. This looks like a difficult combinatorial problem, plus the discrepancy objective may be expensive to evaluate. The Wikipedia page also mentions alternative, cheaper discrepancy measures :

> For instance, L2 discrepancy or modified centered L2 discrepancy are also used intensively to compare the quality of uniform point sets. Both are much easier to calculate for large N and s.